# How to solve "Failed to bind one of the listener ports"?

Tags: help, proxy, support

Can someone please help me with this, or give me a contact email who can? I accidentally did something with the proxy when Tor was open and now I can't reopen it to fix it.

```
3/21/19, 05:42:30.670 [WARN] You specified a public address '23.227.192.139:80' for SocksPort. Other people on the Internet might find your computer and use it as an open proxy. Please don't allow this unless you have a good reason. 
3/21/19, 05:42:30.670 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/21/19, 05:42:30.670 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
3/21/19, 05:42:30.670 [WARN] You specified a public address '23.227.192.139:80' for SocksPort. Other people on the Internet might find your computer and use it as an open proxy. Please don't allow this unless you have a good reason. 
3/21/19, 05:42:30.670 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 23.227.192.139:80 
3/21/19, 05:42:30.670 [WARN] Could not bind to 23.227.192.139:80: Can't assign requested address 
3/21/19, 05:42:30.670 [WARN] Controller gave us config lines that didn't validate: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
```

Comment: Something is either already listening on port 80, or you don’t have permission to bind to port 80, or that IP address is incorrect. Try restarting your computer first, and make sure you’re not running any web servers. If that doesn’t work, edit your torrc file into your post so we can see it. And why did you change your SocksPort setting?